# MySQL PHP record checking

Tags: php, mysql

im having a simple mysql/php problem. so i am adding in Image titles for my website, and the code is displayed below. It works, but when you dont put a image, it shows up as blank. I need it to show up as 'No image title' (bc i will use this for image description to). It basically gets the image name, then takes the title from that row. 
So how do i do it? :/ im still very new to PHP.

```
<?php
 if (isset($imgtitleset)) 
 {
    $sql = "SELECT image_title FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main'";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $imgtitle= $row["image_title"];

       echo "$imgtitle";
    }
 }
 else {
    echo 'no image title'; 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the while loop like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $imgtitle= $row["image_title"];

    if($imgtitle != '') {
        echo $imgtitle;
    } else {
        echo 'no image title';
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what the `$imgtitleset` variable is for, but you can probably get rid of the if statement checking to see whether it's set.

Edit: the whole thing should probably look like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT image_title FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $imgtitle= $row["image_title"];

    if($imgtitle != '') {
        echo $imgtitle;
    } else {
        echo 'no image title';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, yea. i would like to remove it.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you, but it's hard to be 100% sure that's what you need without seeing the rest of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what $imgtitleset is equal to. It is clearly set against something:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $imgtitle = $row["image_title"];
     if (isset($imgtitle))
         echo "$imgtitle";
     else
         echo 'no image title';
 }
```

This would mean if nothing was found in the database then it will echo the no image title. However like I said, this could depend on what `$imgtitleset` is, maybe post the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you only expect the select to return a single row, then use `if` rather than `while` and return the error on `else`:

```
<?php
 if (isset($imgtitleset)) 
 {
    $sql = "SELECT image_title FROM images WHERE image_name = '$image_main'";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $imgtitle= $row["image_title"];
       echo "$imgtitle";
    }
    else {
       echo 'no image title'; 
    }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Currently The isset is not set. I need it remove!